# Android : Paging a view with sliding left or right

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem achiving a sertant effect in a app i am currently working on. The senario is something like this

On my first activity i display a list, and once a item is clicked i display a new activity that holds more details about the item.

Now i want to implement pageing on the detailed page so the user can slide left or right and gets the next or previusly item displayed without having to go back to the list a select.

i got a adapter for the items so it is no biggy getting the information about what item is shown and what the "siblings are"

i have been playing around with the view flipper but as far as i can see it needs the "views" rendered in the stumic of the viewflipper and i dont dare render 300 items out onCreate. any tips on using 3 views and populate em onCreate??

i have called the same activity with and animation so it slides in plus and intent telling what data to show, but it must be poor preformance to do that.

Any ideas ?

if u want to see just that animation/function i want. Tjek out google latitude pageing on u friends detailed page.

//thx in advanced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've implemented the same behavior using `ViewFlipper` with loading the Views on demand.

Here is a snapshot of what I was doing. It's not exactly the same as you wanted, but you can follow the same approach.

```
/**
     * starts a new activity.
     * @param activityToStart the activity class.
     */
    public static void startActivity(Class<?> activityToStart) {
        String name = activityToStart.getName();
        while (history.contains(name)) {
            name += "1";
        }

        View view = activity.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(name,
                new Intent(activity, activityToStart)).getDecorView();

        history.add(name);
        addView(view, name);
    }

     public void addView(View newView, String name) {
    // add its name to the history.
    history.add(name);
    // change the view.
    flipper.addView(newView);
    if(history.size() != 1) {
        flipper.setInAnimation(inFromUpAnimation());

        View oldView = getActivityAt(history.size() - 2);
        flipper.setOutAnimation(outFromBottomAnimation());
        flipper.showNext();
    }
}

private void back() {
   if(history.size() > 1) {
       View oldView = getActivityAt(history.size() - 1);
       flipper.setInAnimation(inFromBottomAnimation());
       setRemoveAnimation(oldView, outToUpAnimation(), history.remove(history.size() - 1));
       flipper.showPrevious();
   } else {
       finish();
   }
}
```

Here I've 3 functions (To start a new activity in your case you might change it to inflate the view if you want, the second that add the view, the third to remove the view when the user hit back).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awsome, it was exactly what i hoped for, populating a viewflipper on demand. do you have some more code on how u inflate your newView and what does u XML markup looks like ?

Comment: OK, I'll edit the post to give you more code. BTW, I was using LocalActivityManager and each view was actually a separate activity. In your case you can just use one activity with different parameters.

Comment: nice mate ill give it a go. and keep this post updated, thx in advanced

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark it as an answer if this is exactly what you want :)

Comment: Sry for the late response, vacation came in the way :) hate all that spare time.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution is to use the new `ViewPager` component from the [Android compatibility package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).